# Different results when running C program from Python Subprocess vs in Bash

Tags: python, c, bash, subprocess, command-line-interface

I've got a string/argument that I'd like to pass to a C program. It's a string format exploit.

```
'\xb2\x33\02\x08%13x%2$n'
```

However, there seems to be different behaviours exhibited if I call the C program from Python by doing

```
subprocess.Popen(["env", "-i", "./practice", '\xb2\x33\02\x08%13x%2$n'])
```

versus

```
./practice '\xb2\x33\02\x08%13x%2$n'
```

The difference is that the string exploit attack works as expected when calling the script via subprocess, but not when I call it through the CLI.

What might the reason be? Thanks.

Comment: Terminal type or characteristics of standard output when the program is run differently.  You may need to investigate “pseudo-ttys”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash manpage says:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to
> string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by  the
> ANSI  C  standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded
> as follows: [snipped]
> **\xHH**   the  eight-bit  character  whose value is the hexadecimal
> value HH (one or two hex digits)

Then would you please try:

```
./practice $'\xb2\x33\02\x08%13x%2$n'
```